# sonar maven plugin fail to download the file: http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar

Tags: maven-plugin, sonarqube

I tried to download and install sonar and then running an analysis with maven sonar plugin.
I have tried first Sonar version 2.14, and now 2.13.1, but I get the same error over and over again.

It seems it is unable to download the jdbc driver from localhost (the sonar server) because I get this error message: "Fail to download the
file: http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar (no proxy): Read timed out -> [Help 1]"

But If I go to http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar with my browser, it downloads the file without problems, so it seems that the sonar server is working the correct way, and that the maven sonar plugin is doing something wrong that I can not figure out.

I have also tried to alter sonar's context root to /sonar, but I get the same error.
I have configured sonar to use postgreSQL instead of the embedded Derby database, but still no luck. Accessing Sonar from a browser works like a charm, but I can not run mvn sonar:sonar so at this point my sonar installation is pretty useless... :(

Here is the stack trace from running maven with the -e option:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project betterfarmer-engine: Can not execute Sonar: Fail to download the
file: http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar (no proxy): Read timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project betterfarmer-engi
ne: Can not execute Sonar
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:118)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:65)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to download the file: http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar (no proxy)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader.download(HttpDownloader.java:130)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ArtifactDownloader.downloadJdbcDriver(ArtifactDownloader.java:58)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.JdbcDriverHolder.<init>(JdbcDriverHolder.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:147)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:319)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:274)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:341)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:689)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:638)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:663)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:113)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.getComponentByType(Module.java:131)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapModule.configure(BootstrapModule.java:63)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.init(Module.java:49)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Module.init(Module.java:41)
        at org.sonar.batch.Batch.<init>(Batch.java:37)
        at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.executeBatch(SonarMojo.java:143)
        at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:136)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:113)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2959)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2953)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1262)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1236)
        at org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader.download(HttpDownloader.java:125)
        ... 48 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: I have also downloaded and tried to run the java sonar-runner. But then I get a similar error saying that it is unable to download the hibernate entity manager, yet still quite possible to do so through a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your Sonar is probably not correctly installed.

- Don't you have errors in the server log?
- Are you able to browse the web application at http://localhost:9000?

I'd suggest to start with a fresh install (in another folder than the previous one) and check that you don't have env properties that point to the previous install location before starting the new Sonar.

Comment: I have tried with a fresh install over and over again. Browsing Sonar through a browser is not a problem - works like a charm. I can also enter the address http://localhost:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.jar directly into the browser, and it will download the jar file.

Comment: It is only the maven-sonar-plugin and the java sonar-runner that fails. I simply can not get any projects analyzed..

Comment: Are you running the analysis on the same machine? Which database are you using? We've already had a couple of questions with the same error on our user mailing list, and IIRC the problem was on the user environment side (some environment properties that were messing up everything, or stuff like that).

Comment: Yes, I am running the analysis on the same machine. At first I was using the embedded derby database, but then I switched to PostgreSQL. I have also set up system properties in my pom.xml like this :
  <sonar.host.url>http://www.bedrebonde.local:9000/</sonar.host.url>
<sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
<sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
<sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>  <sonar.jdbc.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>

Comment: Was it working with Derby when you first tried? And what is this "bedrebonde.local" URL, this does not seem like a avlid URL, does it?

Comment: No, it was not working with Derby. I have tried both with localhost and with bedrebonde.local which is mapped in my hosts file to 127.0.0.1. None of them works. The reason I tried this, is that some network products (like OpenSSO) requires a FQDN to work properly.